# Worklight Push Notification, and SecurityTest

Tags: push-notification, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst, security-testing

I am using Worklight in my iOS and Android Project.
I am also using adapters, with on security test, and using **adapter based authentication**.

I want to use **push notifications**, with users ids recieved from adapter based authentication function. So I use the same **securityTest**.

Now when I try to use my security test with the push event source, I have an error "*Failed to deploy adapter from the database*"

```
WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name : 'MyPushEventSource',
    onDeviceSubscribe : 'deviceSubscribeFunc',
    onDeviceUnsubscribe : 'deviceUnsubscribeFunc',
    securityTest : 'MySecurityTest',
});
```

When I remove the last line (securityTest), the adapter is deployed, when I add it, it fail.

This securityTest is already used with multiple other adapter functions.

Any one can explain me what's wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

edit: Here is my security test definition:

```
<securityTests>
      <customSecurityTest name="MySecurityTest">
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="MyAuthRealm"/>
      </customSecurityTest>
</securityTests>
```

Comment: Can you add here the security test (from authenticationConfig.xml)?

Comment: @KerenBaron-Sela I've just edited the post to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, The solution that worked for me is Adding a new security test, with the same realm, and with type mobileSecurityTest

```
   <mobileSecurityTest name="MyPushSecurityTest">
        <testUser realm="MyAuthRealm"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>
```

I think that this should be added to the current Worklight documentation, or a bug report must be opened.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Now I am gestting again the same error when I add 
 poll : {
  interval : 3,
  onPoll : gotNotificationFromBackEnd,
 },

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no 'MySecurityTest' defined in 'server/conf/authenticationConfig.xml', be sure that you added there a test with this name:

```
<securityTests>
    <customSecurityTest name="MySecurityTest">
        <test realm="..." isInternalUserID="..."/>
    </customSecurityTest>
</securityTests>
```

Comment: The security test is well defined in authenticationConfig.xml, and used with no problem for the adapter functions.
The error comes only when I add it for the push event source!

Comment: Have you tried deleting your adapter and deploying it freshly?

Comment: Same result : 
 FWLSE0082W: Failed to deploy adapter from the database (archive:  '/var/folders/8p/qylwgy6j2wq4bktw4r5hxqvr0000gp/T/myAdapter5096175866595804426.adapter').

Comment: I have seen it before... hrrr... try deleting the WorklightServerHome folder in your workspace and deploy both app and adapter again. See if this workaround works for you.

Comment: I've just tried it, it does not work for me. I have the same result.